# In Delphi, how can I multiply a sql field and a value?

Tags: sql, delphi, firemonkey, pascal, rad-studio

I want to change the text of label1 by multiplying query field with value of spinBox1. But it doesn't work. ** Fields[3] saved as Integer in my table  **

```
label1.Text := MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * spinBox1.Value;
```

or

```
label1.Text := MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * spinBox1.Text.ToInteger;
```

Comment: `MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * spinBox1.Text.ToInteger` is an integer, but `Label1.Text` is a string. You thus need to make a string from the RHS integer: `label1.Text := IntToStr(MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * spinBox1.Text.ToInteger);`. Actually, a bit of experimentation would have made you realise that this has nothing to do with SQL at all: If you had replaced your line with `label1.Text := 5 * 20`, you would have received the same error but with fewer confounders.

Comment: Just use IntToStr function. It is also relatively related to the question, but name your components and variables meaningful and use the FieldByName function instead of the Fields list unless you have any specific reason.

Comment: @LeventÜncü In fact,  when I'm going to ask some people, I make their names as default. Thus, they can understand my problem easier. But thank you for these suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

1. Your application is FMX based then `Label1.Text` is okay, else you need `Label1.Caption`
2. SpinBox comes from FMX library, the `Value` type is `Double`, not an `Integer`

The code is:

```
Label1.Text := (MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * SpinBox1.Value).ToString;
// Or using older versions of Delphi
Label1.Text := FloatToStr(MSQuery1.Fields[3].AsInteger * SpinBox1.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need `Label1.caption` instead of `Label1.Text` and it is a string, so you need `IntToStr` function to convert integer (if it is integer) to string.

Comment: OP is using Firemonkey and not VCL. The TLabel uses a `.Text` property which is a string.